# JS height reset on window resizing

Tags: javascript, resize, height, reset, var

My code works pretty fine for responsive grid on various screen sizes, but only on load, when you resize the window (decreasing the size of window), the variable "MaxHeight" is not decreasing but constant. MaxHeight changes only onLoad, but not when window is resized. Any help?

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var maxHeight = 0;          
$(".photo").each(function(){
  if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
});         
$(".photo").height(maxHeight);
```

});

```
  $(window).resize(function() {
var maxHeight = 0;          
$(".photo").each(function(){
  if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
});         
$(".photo").height(maxHeight);
```

});

And there are multiple divs :

```
    <div class="photo" style="display:table-row; position:relative">
  <a href="#"><img src="link-to-image" style="width: 100%; height: auto"></a>
  <div class="corner">
<span style="font-weight:bold">Lorem Ipsum</span>
<span style="font-style:italic;color:#bebebe;">ipsum</span>  
</div>
</div>

.photo {
width: 33%;
float: left;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 20px;
text-align: center;
/* border: 1px solid black; */
height: auto;
}
```

But the problem appears, while one of 3 columns in a row contains image with larger height, then the whole next row is destroyed.

Comment: Can't you just unset max-height when reaching a breakpoint? `height()` means the height of the element and it will always be equal to `maxHeight` after setting it, thats why it doesnt work on resize.

Comment: Check for the CSS property `max-height`

Comment: I do have a few divs which should be placed:
• in 3 columns on big screens
• in 2 columns on tablet
• in 1 column on mobiles
But when one of the divs is higher than the other in this row, then the next row doesnt fit :/ 

Check out my first post, I've added the code.

Comment: I personally use Masonry for that case (there are a lot of free libraries for this that you can set up in ~10 seconds) or background-image instead of image or flex-based grids.